# Web scraping using BeautifulSoup getting null list

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

> Getting null list while scraping with BeautifulSoup
>   code and the output shown below

[image: the code and the output are shown in the below picture]

What's going wrong?

Comment: are you sure there is something with the class `c_district` in the response?

Comment: yes there are spans with district names and number

Comment: besides that the page has no ```c_district``` class, I am not sure there is no ```class_``` parameter for ```find_all_next``` method.

Comment: @gogulcv if you ```ctrl + u``` and ```ctrl + f``` and search for ```c_district``` you won't find anything. if the page is using JavaScript to update its content, then you should consider using Selenium.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
table = soup.find_all('table', {'id': 'table3'})
```

Hope that helps.